# How to pass whole dictionary in a fabric method in python as its parameter

Tags: python, python-2.7, fabric

I have a dictionary `ex:vars={key:value}`. I need to pass the complete dictionary object i.e, vars in a fabric script in python.

Currently i pass dictionary key like this which runs fine:-

```
local('fab -f path/file.py functionName: %(key)s ' %vars)
```

But I need to pass the vars dictionary object rather than its key.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Python's `json` [module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html), which easily converts dictionaries to strings and vice-versa:

- First, in the file where you call your `fab` command, declare your dictionary, in regular format `{keys:values}`, and then, convert it to a `str`. Make sure, when you write your `fab` that the stringified dictionary is surrounded by single quotes:

`local('fab -f fabfile.py function_name:\'{}\''.format(json.dumps(dictionary)))`

- Then in your function `function_name(str_dictionary)`, add a first-line for converting the string coming from you shell command into a dict:

`real_dictionary = json.loads(str_dictionary)`

**Quick remark to conclude:**

Instead of calling a `fab` command using the `local` function (which is not really in the spirit of Fabric), you should rather put `function_name` in the same file as the one from which you are calling it (or you can even `import` it). Then, you can use Fabric's `execute` function, which allows you to execute a task programmatically, rather than in a shell. Furthermore, `execute` can take as arguments your function's arguments ! That way, you can pass a regular dictionary as a parameter to function_name:

`execute(function_name, {keys:values})`

You can read more about `execute` [here](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.14/api/core/tasks.html)

Comment: when used the step mentioned=  local('fab -f fabfile.py function_name:\'{}\''.format(json.dumps(dictionary))), then it is not able to find the mentioned function and throws error saying use available functions.

Comment: Then can you show me what your `fabfile.py`looks like, and how you call it in your main script ? Be sure to use the `fab` command with the exact function name, as you defined it in your FabFile